# transform HTML string to Angular Components

Tags: angular, angular-aot, angular-elements, angular-dynamic-components, angular-jit

let's say we do an API call and **get some HTML DOM in a String**. The content comes as HTML without angular, so I have first to transform it to Angular where I want and then compile it as angular.

Example API response:

```
<div>
...some more html...
<h1>a header</h1>
...some more html...
<a href="somewhere.com" class="a-class" id="a-id">A Link</a>
...some more html...
</div>
```

I am transforming this to get all Anchors `<a href="x"></a>` and converting them into angular components with inputs and outputs **to be injected in the parent container and parsed all together**, for example:

```
<angular-anchor   
  [href]="somewhere.com"
  [innerClass]="thisClasses"
  [innerID]="thisID" 
  [content]="thisContent">
</angular-anchor>
```

`angular-anchor` contains a click method that execute code from outside these components but inside angular (from a service).

By using `[innerHTML]` in the parent container where the transformation is done by a pipe just before just like:

```
<parent [innerHTML]="APIResponseHTML | transformAnchorsPipe"></parent>
```

**Angular components inside will NOT be loaded** and the whole work is just raw Angular parsed by safeHTML included in the Pipe transformation.

To solve this i used **[ng-dynamic library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic)** but is outdated and **is not compatible with AOT compilation**. Despite this, I manage it to work with JIT compilation but **this is not good for production and a lot less efficient**.

Example of this approach, "parentDIV" is a standard HTML tag:

```
<parentDIV *dynamicComponent="APIResponseHTML | transformAnchorsPipe; 
    context: {dependency: dependencyName};">
</parentDIV>
```

***context*** contains all dependencies required inside the new component, for example my third Service I am using in "angular-anchor"

From this point, I read several documents about **Angular Elements** or **Dynamic Components Injector**, but I could not get with it in my application.

**Is it there any good approach to use my custom angular components available with AOT using these methods I just mentioned or any other?**

Thanks in advance. Ask me for more details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

`<parent [innerHTML]="APIResponseHTML | transformAnchorsPipe"></parent>` inner html is not an known property of `parent` if `parent` is a component

Pass your html as a string to any of the properties in `parent` component - you can achieve using `@Input()` decorator on your properties -  you might have an idea about it

Finally try to pass the string as an inner html to any of your `div` tags in `parent.component.html` - i hope this will parse your html string and append the html inside specified `div`

If this didn't work - try to add `html` encoding for your html string and then try to bind it - hope this will solve your first problem - happy coding :)

Comment: parent is already a div by force at some point if I am using any special feature with the standar way to insert HTML. `InnerHTML` simply will not parse any angular component inside. I will edit my original publication.